# AWS Cross Account Latency while accessing DBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Would there be any latency in accessing data from S3 bucket if move my bucket to another AWS account for security reasons??

I have a service that runs in an AWS account and it uses S3 bucket from the same account. Now, I would like to move my S3 bucket to another account to segregate my service and resource tiers for security reasons. Would this change cost me any latency issues as I would be using assuming roles and going from one vpc and security group to another?

Comment: You should probably keep your assumed session alive and only refresh its credentials occasionally, otherwise the overhead of assume-role before any s3 will certainly have an impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the same region the short answer is no, there would be no added latency or other performance impacts. This is a very common use pattern, and all applicable S3 performance guidelines will still be in effect. Assuming a cross-account role or referencing a principal from another account would not introduce additional latency.